# External monitor moves windows when coming out of sleep (2012 rMBP)

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, display, sleep-wake

I recently purchased a Dell P2715Q for the express purpose of using as the primary display for my 2012 rMBP running 10.10.3 when "docked" at home.  I have the laptop in a vertical holder that holds it in the closed position.  The monitor is connected to the rMBP using a mini display->display port cable, provided by Dell.  In case it matters, max res from the laptop is 2560x1440 (my older rMBP apparently can't handle the full 4k res the monitor can do...whatever).  My rMBP was the top-of-the-line when I bought it, so it has the NVIDIA GT 650M 1gb.

The problem I am having is that all of the windows get shoved into the upper-left corner ever time I wake the laptop from sleep/screensaver.  I am guessing that OS is reverting back to the screen res of the build-in monitor, which has a higher res but smaller desktop real estate, when everything goes to sleep.  This is getting annoying as I typically work with many windows open and placed in particular areas.  How can I tell OS X to stop moving my windows around?

Comment: I think it's really trying to do what it ought - which is that every time a remote screen is removed, it pushes all open windows back to the remaining screen[s]. I'm really not sure you can force it to do otherwise, even if the execution is somewhat lumpy with your 'default' screen being removed.

Comment: Why is the screen being "removed"?  I could understand if I was removing the mDP cable and it was moving the windows, but all it's doing is going to sleep.  Shouldn't it just recognize the display is still there?  This did not happen when I had my old Core Duo MBP plugged into a Cinema display.

Comment: Is is possible it takes a moment for it to detect the clamshell is closed and the screen is connected and that causes it to rearrange the windows. However  try doing a PRAM reset. It’s possibly something skewed in there: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204063

Answer (score 1):

It may be actually worth resetting the NVRAM and SMC (in that order) to see if this resolves your issues. Before doing so, unplug all external devices (including monitors, keyboard, etc).

**Resetting NVRAM on your model MacBook Pro**

Your Mac use Non-Volatile Random-Access Memory (NVRAM) to store a whole range of settings. Here’s how to reset this:

1. **Shut down your Mac.** Yes, a full shut down, not just logging out.
2. Press the <kbd>power button</kbd> *and then* press the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>P</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> keys. You have to make sure you press these keys **before** the gray screen appears or it won’t work.
3. **Hold those keys down** until your Mac reboots again and you here the startup chime for the second time.
4. Let go of the keys and let your Mac reboot normally.

**Note:** When you log back in you ***may*** need to readjust some of your system preferences (e.g. speaker volume, screen resolution, startup disk selection, time zone information, etc).

Now proceed to reset the SMC.

**Resetting the SMC on your model MacBook Pro**

The System Management Controller (SMC) impacts a whole range of power management functions. Here's how to reset this:

1. Shut down your computer
2. **Disconnect** the MagSafe plug (power cable) from the computer
3. Remove the battery
4. Press the <kbd>power button</kbd> for 5 seconds and release
5. Put the battery back in
6. Reconnect the MagSafe cord (or power cable)
7. Turn your computer back on with the power button